# Draggable Item from component A to B

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-beautiful-dnd

Is it possible to render the columns within different components and be able to drag items from B -> A and A -> B

[image]

There will always be **1 column in Component A and 1+ in B**. I'm not sure how I can go about doing this? Do I need two DragDropContext to one in A and B? Can someone give me some guidance on how I can achieve this?

Here is a working example:

Currently, this could be Component B however if I try to implement component A how can I move items between the two.

[image: Edit react-beautiful-dnd tutorial]

Comment: You don't need to re-invent the wheel. Get this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-draggable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the docs you would not need to have more than one `DragDropContext` in the same parent Hierarchy.

So for you use case, I can envision it looking something like this.

```
<App>
   <ComponentA />

   <ComponentB />
</App>
```

Each of the component `ComponentA` and `ComponentB` will be wrapped in a `Droppable`.

And each column in you case will be `Draggable`.

```
   <App>
      <DragDropContext>
         <Droppable>
           <ComponentA>
              <Draggable>
                <Column />
              </Draggable>
           </ComponentA>
         </Droppable>

         <Droppable>
           <ComponentB>
              <Draggable>
                <Column />
              </Draggable>

              <Draggable>
                 <Column />
              </Draggable>
           </ComponentB>
         </Droppable>
    </App>
```

This is a high level overview on how the hierarchy might look like. ( The top level comp returned by `JSX` of `Column` can be `Droppable`. Like wise for other components. )

Comment: Looking at my initialdata in codesandbox. Would you say I need a new InitialData2 = { ... } if I simply just want only one column in component A?

Comment: @Freddy. Not really. As long as you have a mapping of which task falls under which column one object should be good enough. That is the reason for the key `taskIds: ['task-1', 'task-2', 'task-3', 'task-4']` which states that `column-1` has the following tasks listed

Comment: that is true however with the current implementation. I use map() function to map to populate all column within component B. If I do the same to component A there be more than 1 column. So having said this, I may need another object with only 1 column with the same data structure however it will still allow me to move A->B and B->A

Comment: @Freddy It all depends on the data structure that you want to use. If there is correlation between different objects, it just depends on how you envision it. You can get the same thing working with a single object or having multiple objects and then have a mapping some how.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thanks for the high-level overview.